# Django deployment error in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, deployment, hosting, pythonanywhere

After finishing all the steps of deployment in pythonanywhere.com I got the error at wsgi.py file

To remove the error and make the django application live. I have got the error at line:31 of wsgi.py file. At the part of DJANGO settings.

Comment: It is necessary to include the code snippet and the error message for others to understand the condition. And You could remove sensitive information in your code first.

Comment: Need a screenshot of the error